# Constant missing .type.xml error in Spoon when opening team repositories

Tags: pentaho, kettle, spoon

I get many, many errors when I open or work with jobs and transformations. They all say:

> Unable to load XML metastore element type from file '[filepath to repo].meta\metastore\pentaho\Default Run Configuration.type.xml'

This is when I open projects from other team members. My own projects are fine. I can close these errors with no apparent consequences, but can anyone assist me on how to eliminate these?

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration version 7.1.

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: Version 7.1. I should've included that in the post, so I added it.